# VB.NET: Searching for certain values in text

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, parsing

I have programmed a piece of code that reads a String and tries to get certain parts out of it.

In particular, I want to get the numbers that are contained in a custom textual  written tag: `[propertyid=]`. For example `[propertyid=541]` would need to return me `541`.

This search and retrieve happens in a text and needs to occur as often as the amount of tags there are in the text.

I already have written out code that works

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim properties As New List(Of String)
       'context of string doesn't matter, only the ids are important
        Dim text As String = "Dit is de voorbeeld string. Eerst komt er gewoon tekst. Daarna een property als [propertyid=1155641] met nog wat tekst. Dan volgt nog een [propertyid=1596971418413399] en dan volgt het einde."
        Dim found As Integer = 1

        Do
            found = InStr(found, text, "[propertyid=")
            If found <> 0 Then
                properties.Add(text.Substring(found + 11, text.IndexOf("]", found + 11) - found - 11).Trim())
                found = text.IndexOf("]", found + 11)
            End If
        Loop While found <> 0




        Console.WriteLine("lijst")
        For Each itemos As String In properties
            Console.WriteLine(itemos)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

But I can't help but feel like this isn't optimal. I'm pretty sure this can be written way easier or with the help of other tools than `Substring` and `IndexOf`. Especially so, because of the fact that I need to play a bit with the indexes and the loop.

Any suggestions for improving this piece of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) for this kind of task.

In this case, the pattern to match `[propertyid=NNNN]` is:

`\[propertyid=(\d+)\]`

Which isolates a set of one or more digits - `\d+` - in a capture group (the parentheses) so it can be retrieved by the matching engine.

Here's a code example:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim properties As New List(Of String)
        'context of string doesn't matter, only the ids are important
        Dim text As String = "Dit is de voorbeeld string. Eerst komt er gewoon tekst. Daarna een property als [propertyid=1155641] met nog wat tekst. Dan volgt nog een [propertyid=1596971418413399] en dan volgt het einde."
        Dim pattern As String = "\[propertyid=(\d+)\]"

        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
            properties.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
        Next

        For Each s As String In properties
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thx! Guess I forgot these existed.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helped.